# Iframe class display none in WordPress does not work

Tags: iframe, hide, display

I am trying to hide elements (the `.row` class) of an IFrame and tried the following, but it does not work:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('row').style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok if i understand you right:
You cannot modify the content of the iframe because of security reasons. (Third party logins, etc)
You have to put the javascript right into the iframes source.

Comment: I want to iframe just the map of this website: http://www.apotheken.de/apotheken-und-notdienste-suchen/

Is there another solution? I put that whole site into iframe, but thats not, what I actually want.

Comment: Du könntest das iframe in ein kleineres Div packen und die leiste mit overflow:none verstecken.